# recursion - remove Nodes if their String is "Leonardo"

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I've a tree of nodes.

```
class Node {
    String mName;
    List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
    Node(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }
}
```

I want to check all the tree nodes and if I find some Node with the mName of "Leonardo", I will want to add all Leonardo's children to Leonardo's father and remove Leonardo himself.

**For example**

The initial tree is:

```
                        Jessy
                   /      |       \
 Leonardo                John                  Leonardo
 /     \                 /   \                  /   \
Rafael  David      Leonardo   Keren         Denis  Leonardo
                                                       |
                                                   Phillipe
```

the result should be:

```
                        Jessy
                   /      |       \
 Rafael  David           John         Denis  Phillipe
                          |             
                        Keren
```

(Explanation about the result of the sub tree of Leonardo, Denis, Phillipe and Leonardo: the third son of Jessy is Leonardo so Leonardo is removed and his sons(Denis and Leonardo) become the sons of Jessy. But then the another Leonardo is removed and Phillipe comes instead of him.)

The order of the children doesn't matter (i.e, Rafael and David could come after Phillipe)

Assume that there is NO way to get initial tree when "Leonardo" is in the root.

I've tried this but it doesn't work unfortunately..

```
for (int i = 0; i < root.children.size(); ++i) {
        removeLeonardo(root, root.children.get(i));
}

public void removeLeonardo(Node curr, Node child) {
    if (child == null || child.children.isEmpty() == true) {
        return;
    }

    if (child.mName.equals("Leonardo") == true) {
        // add all Leonardo's children to current father
        for (int i = 0; i < child.children.size(); ++i) {
            curr.children.add(child.children.get(i));
            // apply the func for the current father with each of Leonardo's children
            removeLeonardo(curr, child.children.get(i));
        }
        // remove "Leonardo" from the current father
        curr.children.remove(child);
    }

    else { // no "Leonardo" found, so apply the func for each child and this child's children
        for (int i = 0; i < child.children.size(); ++i) {
            removeLeonardo(child, child.children.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

but Java doesn't work by reference. Can you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should work.

If you're worried about efficiency then deleting from and inserting into the interior of an ArrayList isn't the best. A LinkedList would be better, but then you wouldn't want to access children by their index. You'd probably use a ListIterator instead, and use the add and remove methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Node root = new Node("Jessy");
    root.children.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Node[]{new Node("Leonardo"), new Node("John"), new Node("Leonardo")}));      
    root.children.get(0).children.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Node[]{new Node("Rafael"), new Node("David")}));
    root.children.get(1).children.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Node[]{new Node("Leonardo"), new Node("Keren")}));
    root.children.get(2).children.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Node[]{new Node("Denis"), new Node("Leonardo")}));
    root.children.get(2).children.get(1).children.add(new Node("Phillipe"));

    print(root, "");                
    pruneByName(root, "Leonardo");
    print(root, "");
}

static void pruneByName(Node node, String name)
{       
    assert !node.mName.equals(name);

    for(int i=0; i<node.children.size(); )
    {
        Node child = node.children.get(i);
        if(child.mName.equals(name))
        {
            node.children.remove(i);
            node.children.addAll(i, child.children);
        }
        else
        {
            pruneByName(child, name);
            i += 1;
        }
    }
}

static void print(Node node, String ind)
{
    System.out.println(ind + node.mName);
    for(Node child : node.children)
    {
        print(child, ind + "  ");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Jessy
  Leonardo
    Rafael
    David
  John
    Leonardo
    Keren
  Leonardo
    Denis
    Leonardo
      Phillipe
Jessy
  Rafael
  David
  John
    Keren
  Denis
  Phillipe
```

Answer (score 1):

The child John is being skipped in the initial loop. Here's how.

Jessy's children Leonardo, John, etc are at index 0, 1, etc in the array list.
The `for` loop starts at index 0 processing the first Leonardo, and that Leonardo
is removed. In the process of removing Leonardo, John, who was at index 1,
is moved to index 0. The for loop then moves onto index 1 skipping John and
not removing John's child, Leonardo.

Below is code using `ListIterator`'s that should solve the problem. With this
code you can use any type of list including `LinkedList`'s as well as `ArrayList`'s.

```
public static void removeLeonardo2(Node node) {
    if (node == null || node.children.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    for(ListIterator<Node> it = node.children.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Node n;
        n = it.next();
        if(n.mName.equals("Leonardo")) {
            removeLeonardo2(n);
            it.remove();
            for(Node childNode: n.children) {
                it.add(childNode);;
            }
        }else {
            removeLeonardo2(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @YvetteColomb :)